# Can't center PercentRelativeLayout in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, frontend

I have a Fragment which has a square camera (width & height are both equal to the screens width) represented as a FrameLayout in a PercentRelativeLayout. Underneath this camera is an ImageView that takes the picture when clicked.

I would like to center the square camera vertically (since it already covers the screens width) and then center the ImageView underneath it in the space that's left. This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/llCameraFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvCamera"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="100%" />
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBelowCamera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCaptureImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camerashutter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the camera view (PercentRelativeLayout) is always starting from the very top of the screen. I've tried using `layout_gravity` instead of `gravity` in the PercentRelativeLayout, and also tried wrapping it around a LinearLayout with the gravity set to center / center_vertical.

Any idea what could be wrong? Appreciate any efforts :)

Comment: Can you explain what layout are you trying to achieve? You have a frameLayout inside of percentLayout with 100% width

Comment: I want the camera view to be a square that fills the screens width. For it to be a square, I need its height to be equal to that width. I'm achieving this using a PercentRelativeLayout to hold the camera fragment (FrameLayout)

Comment: I think you might be better off using `ConstraintLayout` in this case

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are trying to achieve using `ConstraintLayout`. As you can see, it is much easier and much more efficient.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/tvCamera"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivCaptureImage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvCamera"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if you end up using this and if you need any more help